# When using HuggingFace's Transformers library to run the GLUE benchmark, is it possible to load my own model from a PVC without using ModelHub?

Tags: nlp, benchmarking, huggingface-transformers, kubernetes-pvc

So HuggingFace's transformers library has a nice script [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/tree/main/examples/pytorch/text-classification) which one can use to test a model which exists on their ModelHub against the GLUE benchmark. However, I have a model which I wish to test whose weights are stored in a PVC on my university's cluster, and I am wondering if it is possible to load directly from there, and if so, how.

Otherwise, could anyone point me in the direction of something which could do what I wish to do? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume the PVC is mounted and you can access it `/bla/bla/mymodel_dir/`? If this is the case then you can use that script as it is. Just pass the path to the model to the parameter `model_name_or_path`. You can also try it first without the script in a python shell. `from transformers import AutoModel` and `m = AutoModel.from_pretrained("/bla/bla/mymodel_dir/")`

Comment: That's exactly what I had been wondering, thank you very much!